Unable to connect to postgres database running in oracle cloud
I run postgres in a docker container on oracle cloud. I opened the port with iptables and via the oracle cloud web interface.
Somehow I can still not connect to the database using Datagrip. I also tried postgres.js, because that is what I would like to use to connect to it.
This is what i get, when it is not running:
DBMS: PostgreSQL (no ver.)
Case sensitivity: plain=mixed, delimited=exact
Connection to 000.000.000.000:<port> refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

This is what I get, when the database is running:
DBMS: PostgreSQL (no ver.)
Case sensitivity: plain=mixed, delimited=exact
Der Verbindungsversuch schlug fehl.

The errors I get using postgres.js:
when it is not running:
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 000.000.000.000:<port>
    at __node_internal_captureLargerStackTrace (node:internal/errors:496:5)
    at __node_internal_exceptionWithHostPort (node:internal/errors:671:12)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1555:16)
    at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:128:17) {
  errno: -4039,
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '000.000.000.000:<port>',
  port: <port>
}

when it is running:
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 000.000.000.000:<port>
    at __node_internal_captureLargerStackTrace (node:internal/errors:496:5)
    at __node_internal_exceptionWithHostPort (node:internal/errors:671:12)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1555:16)
    at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:128:17) {
  errno: -4078,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '000.000.000.000:<port>',
  port: <port>
}

docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:16.3
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: nuxai
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass
      POSTGRES_DB: nuxai
    ports:
      - "<port>:<port>"
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

output of sudo ss -nlpt | grep 5432:
LISTEN 0 65535 0.0.0.0:54320 0.0.0.0:* users:(("docker-proxy",pid=10770,fd=4)) 
LISTEN 0 65535 [::]:54320 [::]:* users:(("docker-proxy",pid=10777,fd=4))


Hi,
Have you configured Oracle Cloud firewall to expose(make public) desired ports?

@VasiliiChernov Yes. I should have wrote that. I opened the port in the firewall settings using iptables and in the Oracle Cloud Web-Interface too. I think that worked, because I get a different error, when the database is running (see post). The problem is, that I can still not connect. Nevermind, I did write that.
